# python gui (creating button with command function that takes in an argument)

Tags: python, user-interface, button

I'm trying to create a set of buttons that when you click on them you can upload files. Each button is initialized like so:

```
self.initialOpenButton = Button(self.firstFrame,text='Open',command=self.getInitialFile)
```

Each of the buttons calls a function getInitialFile, but I'd like getInitialFile to take in an index, representing which button it is. But I've realized that if I do getInitialFile(index) it will automatically open the uploading file prompt even when the button hasn't been clicked.

Is there a way to assign to command a function that takes in an argument? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the button with left click middle click and rightclick and then onclick you can call function getInitialFile